# How to prefer prefix over a general "like" result?

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say I have the following columns that would be selected when I use `%un%` as a `LIKE` search:

```
fun
unlikely
mundane
```

But what I want is for the prefixed results to show up first - so basically, they will be returned in the following order:

```
unlikely
fun
mundan
```

Is there a simple way to do this in MySQL, or will I simply have to modify the array of results after I get them in PHP?

I was going to do it on the PHP side, although I'm not sure if there's a MySQL way of doing it.

Comment: @cybermonkey I think the question is very clear

Comment: The question is very clear @cybermonkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add an

```
order by left (column,2) = 'un' desc
```

That will put them at the top